# Структура БД галереи картинок товара Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Всем привет! Нужен совет, каким образом заполнить БД, чтобы можно было выводить неограниченное количество картинок.
С помощью `slick-slider + fancybox-3` сделал галерею для товара. Код выглядит так. Для примера взял 3 картинки, но по идее их можно будет потом автоматически через админку добавлять и их может быть неограниченное количество.

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 row-box">
          <div class="productslider__big">
            <a href="/img/jpg&png/products/img_00001.jpg" data-fancybox="gallery-1"><img class="prodimgbig" src="/img/jpg&png/products/img_00001.jpg"></a>
            <a href="/img/jpg&png/products/img_00002.jpg" data-fancybox="gallery-1"><img class="prodimgbig" src="/img/jpg&png/products/img_00002.jpg"></a>
            <a href="/img/jpg&png/products/img_00003.jpg" data-fancybox="gallery-1"><img class="prodimgbig" src="/img/jpg&png/products/img_00003.jpg"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="productslider__small">
            <div><img class="prodimgsmall" src="/img/jpg&png/products/img_00001.jpg"></div>
            <div><img class="prodimgsmall" src="/img/jpg&png/products/img_00002.jpg"></div>
            <div><img class="prodimgsmall" src="/img/jpg&png/products/img_00003.jpg"></div>
          </div>
      </div><!--end col-->
```

В БД у товара у меня всего одно поле "img". В нем я храню ссылку на картинку, которая находится в `public/img`. Каким образом создать БД, чтобы количество картинок могло быть динамическим?
Чето нашел про `json_decode`, как понял можно в одном поле много ссылок прописать, а эта функция их разобьет по отдельности? Как в таком случает должно выглядеть поле с картинками в БД?
Извиняюсь если банальный вопрос, решение пока не смог найти, застрял на этом моменте.

Comment: Ну json-поле - это своеобразный костыль, который будет работать.
Можете нормализовать таблицу с товарами, для этого заведите ещё одну таблицу с полями good_id (foreign key на id в таблице с товарами), value (ссылка), id (primary key). И туда уже пишите построчно каждую ссылку отдельно. В случае чего можно будет удалить определенную, не задевая остальные.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Создаете отдельную таблицу для картинок **images** с foreign key `product_id` и столбцами `path` и `position` для сортировки.
2. Прописываете в модель **Product** отношение для картинок **hasMany**.
3. Для модели **Image** отношение **belongsTo**.

Comment: Для Image нужно отдельную модель создать? 
А position каким образом должен сортировать и для чего? Типо 1 для основного изображения, 2 для превью? Либо чтобы изображения, добавленные позже для товара не потерялись?

Comment: 1. Можно сделать и на "сырых" запросах. Все зависит от вашего уровня.
2. Да. Что бы иметь порядок. Если загрузить 5 картинок с помощью `position` можно определить порядок в каком они будут выводиться. Вывести только превью и тп.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!